# Select update function for dynamic selectboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've created a script that fills a selectbox with content depending of what is selected in the previous selectbox. The script itself works perfectly but I have one problem left.

When I select something in selectbox2 then selectbox3 is filled with content. The problem however is that when I decide to change selectbox2 again I can't select the first option of slectbox3.

So lets say:

Selectbox1 (not dynamic):
- Apple (selected)
- Samsung
- Huawei

Selectbox2 (dynamic content):
- Ipad
- Iphone (selected)
- Ipod

Selectbox3 (dynamic content):
- Iphone3
- Iphone4
- Iphone5 (selected)

So right now I am in selectbox3. When I decide to change Selectbox1 or Selectbox2 into something else the selectbox isn't updating to the newly selected option.

I've read a few things about this and I think it has something to do with a `trigger('update')` function.

I tried this with:

`var $select = $('#id-from-selectbox');`
and then update the selectbox with:
`$select.trigger('update')`

You can see the script in action here -> [here](http://new-parts4gsm.webshopapp.com/nl/) (under "wat zoekt u?")

I'm really completely stuck on this one. Any help more then welcome!

So my HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="compatible">
    <div class="zoeken-select">
        <div id="optieEen" class="zoeken-value">Selecteer een merk</div>
        <div class="zoeken-handle"></div>
        <select id="changeEen" name="changeEen" class="gui-validate selector">
            <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Selecteer een merk</option>
            <option id="1782331" value="1782331">Apple</option>
            <option id="1782359" value="1782359">BlackBerry</option>
            <option id="1782401" value="1782401">HTC</option>
            <option id="1782485" value="1782485">Huawei</option>
            <option id="1782509" value="1782509">LG</option>
            <option id="1782577" value="1782577">Motorola</option>
            <option id="1782587" value="1782587">Nokia</option>
            <option id="1782735" value="1782735">Samsung</option>
            <option id="1782889" value="1782889">Sony Ericsson</option>
            <option id="1782937" value="1782937">Sony</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="zoeken-select">
        <div id="optieTwee" class="zoeken-value">Selecteer een serie</div>
        <div class="zoeken-handle"></div>
        <select class="gui-validate selector" name="changeTwee" id="changeTwee">
            <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Selecteer een serie</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="zoeken-select">
        <div id="optieDrie" class="zoeken-value">Selecteer een model</div>
        <div class="zoeken-handle"></div>
        <select class="gui-validate selector" name="changeDrie" id="changeDrie">
            <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Selecteer een model</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="zoeken-select">
        <div id="optieVier" class="zoeken-value">Selecteer een onderdeel</div>
        <div class="zoeken-handle"></div>
        <select class="gui-validate selector" name="changeVier" id="changeVier">
            <option selected="" disabled="" value="">Selecteer een onderdeel</option>
        </select>
    </div> <a title="Inloggen" href="#" onclick="go_category();" class="zoekbtn btn btn-custom">Search</a>

</form>

var categoryUrl = '';
$('#selector-widget .selector').change(function () {
    var selectVal = $(this).val();
    var selectName = $(this).attr('name');

    $.getJSON('link-to-json?format=json', function(data){
            $.each(data.shop.categories, function(i, category) {
              var mainCatId = category.id;
              if(selectName == 'changeEen') {
                $("#optieEen").html($("#changeEen option:selected").text());
                if(category.id == selectVal) {
                  categoryUrl = category.url;
                  $('#changeTwee .cat-new').remove();
                  if(category.subs) {
                    var $select = $('#changeTwee');
                    $.each(category.subs, function(i, category) {
                      $('#changeTwee').append('<option class="cat-new" value="'+category.id+'">'+category.title+'</option>');
                    });
                    $select.trigger('update');
                  }
                }
              } else {
                if(category.subs) {
                  $.each(category.subs, function(i, category) {
                    if(selectName == 'changeTwee') {
                      $("#optieTwee").html($("#changeTwee option:selected").text());
                      if(category.id == selectVal) {
                        categoryUrl = category.url;
                        $('#changeDrie .cat-new').remove();
                        if(category.subs) {
                          var $select = $('#changeDrie');
                          $.each(category.subs, function(i, category) {
                            $('#changeDrie').append('<option class="cat-new" value="'+category.id+'">'+category.title+'</option>');
                          });
                          $select.trigger('update');
                        }
                      }
                    } else {
                      if(category.subs) {
                        $.each(category.subs, function(i, category) {
                          if(selectName == 'changeDrie') {
                            $("#optieDrie").html($("#changeDrie option:selected").text());
                            if(category.id == selectVal) {
                              categoryUrl = category.url;
                              $('#changeVier .cat-new').remove();
                              $.getJSON(categoryUrl+'/?format=json', function(data) {
                                var $select = $('#changeVier');
                                $.each(data.collection.filters.custom, function(index, filter) {
                                  if(filter.id == '9041') {
                                    $.each(filter.values, function(index, value) {
                                      $('#changeVier').append('<option class="cat-new" value="'+value.id+'">'+value.title+'</option>');
                                    });
                                  }
                                });
                                $select.trigger('update');
                              });                                     
                            }
                          } else {
                            if(selectName == 'changeVier'){
                              $("#optieVier").html($("#changeVier option:selected").text());
                              if(category.subs) {
                                $.each(category.subs, function(i, category) {
                                  $('#changeVier').append('<option class="cat-new" value="'+category.id+'">'+category.title+'</option>');
                                });
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        });
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }
              }        
            });  
          });
});

function go_category() {
    if ($("select#changeVier").val() != '') {
        categoryUrl = categoryUrl + '/?filter[]=' + $("select#changeVier option:selected").val();
    } else {
        categoryUrl = categoryUrl;
    }
    window.location = categoryUrl;
}
```

Comment: In the fiddle, even the second selectbox does not seem to get filled.

Comment: please provide a working jsfiddle with the relevant code

Comment: Are you using some plugin for select list? or it is plain html select list?

Comment: @BeNdErR: I created a Fiddle but I can't get it to work properly so that it generates the same "error" as in the test script which can be found in the link that's in my post.

Comment: @aSharma: I'm not using a plugin of any kind. It's just plain reading of JSON content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
$select.trigger('update');
```

To this:

```
$select.val(null).trigger('change')
```

And I think you're all set.

The `.val(null)` clears any selection that is already there, and `'change'` is the correct event that updates the div which is displaying the selected value.

**Edit:**

By calling `.trigger('change')` we are simulating the user making a change on the select box. Since this line is in the handler for the `change` event of the select (so that it runs when the user makes a change), this line should also run when the previous select simulates a change. It's a chain reaction. The first select causes the second to `change`, and the second causes the third to `change` and so on.

Comment: Awesome :) Almost what I'm looking for.... Is it possible to set all selectboxes to `null` when you change a selectbox? So when sb1 + sb2 + sb3 is selected and I change sb1 to something else that sb2 and sb3 are set to `null`? Right now only sb2 is set to null... Anyway thx for your heads up....

Comment: This wasn't a problem for me in my testing. Check the paragraph that I've added to my answer. See if you can get this working. If not, the other option would be copying the `trigger` line for each other select that needs to be called.